# how sizeof works on unimplemented function?

Tags: c++, c

I have two functions without any implementation.

I expect that the linker returns an undefined reference to hello and world error.

But surprisingly, the code compiles and runs without any error.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int hello();
char world();

int main() {
  printf("sizeof hello = %zu, sizeof world = %zu\n", sizeof(hello()), sizeof(world()));
}
```

```
sizeof hello = 4, sizeof world = 1
```

Comment: You don't need the definition to tell what the return type is.

Comment: The size of what a function returns does not depend on its definition.

Comment: "When applied to an expression, `sizeof` does not evaluate the expression (i.e. the expression is an unevaluated operand)". In other words, `sizeof` looks at the tins label but not the contents inside the tin

Comment: `sizeof()` returns `size_t`, not `long int`.  The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.  `%ld` is wrong, and while it might work on Linux or other systems, it *will* emit wrong data on 64-bit Windows, where `long int` is only 32 bits.

Comment: Remember that `sizeof` is a **keyword**, not a **function**. `sizeof(f())` will not evaluate `f()`.

Comment: https://softans.com/question/how-sizeof-works-on-unimplemented-function/#comment-483

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sizeof(hello())` is the size of the the return type, `int`, not the size of the function.  The function is not called.

The function does not need to be defined to determine its return type declared by `int hello();`.

---

**Deeper (in C)**

`sizeof` works with `sizeof unary-expression` and `sizeof ( type-name )`.

> The **size is determined from the type of the operand**. The result
> is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the **operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant. C17dr § 6.5.3.4 2

Since the type of the operand `hello()` is an `int` (and not a variable length array), the operand is not evaluated and is then like `sizeof(int)`.

---

Aside: `sizeof` returns a `size_t`.

`"%zu"` is a correct specifier to match a `size_t`.  `"%ld"` is not specified to work.

```
// printf("sizeof hello = %ld, sizeof world = %ld\n", sizeof(hello()), sizeof(world()));
printf("sizeof hello = %zu, sizeof world = %zu\n", sizeof(hello()), sizeof(world()));
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is unevaluated context. It does not actually call the functions. No definition is required. The declaration is sufficient to know that they  return `int` and `char`.

You could as well have written `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char)` to get the same output. `sizeof(&hello)` would result in the size of a function pointer to `hello` and does not require the definition either. And `sizeof(hello)` just makes no sense, because functions have no size (at least not in a sense that `sizeof` could tell you).

For details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof (c++) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof (c).

Comment: Unless there's a special case for `sizeof` that I'm not remembering, `sizeof(hello)` should be equivalent to `sizeof(&hello)`.

Comment: @zwol  This answer has the relevant quotes from the C standard https://stackoverflow.com/a/75385845/4117728. I guess similar can be found in the C++ standard

Comment: @zwol `sizeof` is not a function, so the usual to pointer decay doesnt happen

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question:

> **how sizeof works on unimplemented function?**

implies you are trying to determine how much memory the function implementation uses, similar to `sizeof()` `int` returning how much memory an `int` variable uses.

You can't use `sizeof()` on a function like that.

Per [**6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**, paragraph 1 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p1):

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type...

The [draft C23 standard](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.5.3.4) has the exact same wording:

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type...